# How do [n&1] and [n%2] work?

Tags: c++

Can I get a detailed description or documentation how these operators work intrinsically? When applied the output is the same.  So far I've found very little to nothing on the subject.

Comment: The compiler may optimize them to perform the same, intrinsically.

Comment: Print the assembly language for both statements and compare.  Also compare the assembly language at different optimization levels.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews When `mod`ding by powers of two, as in the headline, yes.

Comment: @Alex you're probably getting downvoted because it's quite trivial to look up what C++ operators do. If you already checked those resources, and they did not answer your question, you should explain why, to both avoid downvotes and make your question clearer.

Comment: It's not hard to look up: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic

Comment: @KeithM thank you.  I understand and appreciate not asking trivial questions.  Although I do think my question was clear.

Answer (score 6):

*In Theory*, `n&1` masks off or keeps only the lowest order bit of a number.

The `n%2` divides `n` by `2` and returns the remainder.

Both are common tests for to see if a number is even or odd.

The compiler is allow to substitute equivalent functionality for the expression.  So the compiler may emit instructions for `n&1` for both cases.

Print the assembly language listing for the function under different optimization levels.

Comment: `&` is called [**bit-wise operator**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ke0e88k.aspx).

Comment: @FirstStep: where do I mention the operator?  I know it is one of many bitwise operators.  It is called "bitwise AND" or "arithmetic AND".

Comment: No offense Thom. My comment was for the sake of improving your answer to the OP since you did not include its name. And I am not a down voter..

Comment: The internet is a strange place.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Nope. But it's filled with strange people

Comment: @ThomasMatthews yes there are strange ppl for sure.  The assembly language listing was exactly what was looking for. Thank you.